# Django or Flask or Falcon for Microservices

Tags: python

Why is Microservice Architecture better than monolithic architecture? I know the answer will be because the microservice architecture is more scalable and each service is independent of each other etc.

My following question is: should we build using Flask or Django REST Framework?

I have also heard of a framework know as [Falcon](http://falconframework.org) as per there documentation seems good enough.

Comment: I'm tempted to answer but usually these questions get closed down (claim is they are too opinionated). However even a "monolithic" framework like Django could be used to build a microservice, as long as you deploy it to serve a single purpose and provide a way for the service to be found by the other services. So really you can use any framework that you like. Nothing at this point of your requirements (as seen in the question) is going to dictate which _web_ framework is better.

Comment: @Aamir: I don't think one or the other is better in general, it is more about what is more suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 18):

### Microservices is an architecture, not a *web** framework choice

I don't think whether your app turns out to be a monolith or a microservice depends on the web framework that you are using (e.g. Django or Flask)

*Unless we're talking about frameworks specifically built to deal with managing microservices (e.g. to facilitate service discovery) web frameworks like Django or Flask are pretty equivalent (input HTTP request, output HTTP response)

Maybe their *perceived popularity* in a given use case (e.g. Django monolith or Flask microservice) may suggest they are better suited for a particular deployment style, but you could a microservice with Django just as easily as you can a monolith with Flask.

For instance, if I select Flask as my web framework, and in a single Flask app/process I implement all of the services (auth, admin, reporting, payroll, marketing, billing, messaging, search etc), where everything communicates on the code level, then I'd end up with a monolith.

On the other hand, if for instance I take Django, and divide my services into several small Django deploys, and make it so they only communicate through well defined HTTP contracts, and can be updated/deployed independently, then I'd end up with a microservice.

Bottom line is, a microservice is more than just the web framework you use, so use whichever one you like the most, until you have more specific requirements and e.g. 3rd party libs that are useful to you and are only available for a given framework but not the other.

Comment: What do I do in a situation where different django microservices need to utilize common database models. Say, a Database Model in an Application utilizes a database model in another application as a ForeignKey. How would I point to the model in another Application to be a Foreign Key Field in a model in another application. I come from an entirely monolithic background and do not know whether it is possible to implement something like this using Django.

Comment: Say, I want to implement a microservice architecture using Django as a web framework of choice. Then the question really boils down to how do I access database models across my application?

Comment: @DivijSehgal I'm not experienced with services that have FKs to each other, but let's say you have Django A and Django B running as two services, if you want to use have an FK from B to A, in B you could have a Django `Model` with [`managed = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed), that way you are linked through the lower level database FK, and do not need access to Django A's `models.py`, and since that model is not managed by B, Django A has full control on its definition and migrations.

Comment: The problem comes when you break the two apps out of a single monolith django project and into two separate microservices; they are converted into two separate Django Projects, running separately. In such a case(and this is me guessing), would I need to resort to running queries on the database rather than use the Django ORM?

Comment: You won't necessarily _have_ to drop to raw SQL, since with the unmanaged Django model mentioned above you can still use a model that isn't managed by the same Django app, it could be an existing SQL table that stands by itself, or a SQL table that is managed by another app/service (Django, Flask, anything).

Comment: How would I refer to that model from within another external application?

Comment: As in how else would I refer to that Database Model's records, when I want to run a `ModelInA.objects.get()` sort of operation from within application B?

Comment: The model is (re)defined in the external app that uses it (B), because otherwise you would depend on the `models.py` of app (A) which defeat the purpose of a  separate service. It's defined in B, but managed by A (creation, migration of DB tables). This is suggested if you'd like to use Django ORM on that table instead of raw SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156946/discussion-between-divij-sehgal-and-bakkal).